# javascript fetch() arrayBuffer acting strange

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am not a hardcore javascript user. I am trying to edit a pdf and add additional information. For that I am using PDF-LIB (or I am trying to). In the example code on their [github](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib) page. They are using a await fetch() method that then returns a arrayBuffer.

It needs to run in a local envirement without the need to install several dependencies or big packages.

When I exactly copy their code everything works. I fetch the pdf from a cors allowed example pdf and no issue.

But when I change the code to get a pdf from my assets folder the arrayBuffer stays empty. What is diffrent with fetching localy or on the same server then getting it from their host?

```html
<!-- https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>pdf-lib test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/main.css">
    <script src="./assets/js/pdf-lib.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/download.js"></script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div>
        <p>Click the button to modify an existing PDF document with <code>pdf-lib</code></p>
        <button onclick="modifyPdf()">Modify PDF</button>
        <p class="small">(Your browser will download the resulting file)</p>
    </div>
</body>
    
<script>
const { degrees, PDFDocument, StandardFonts, rgb } = PDFLib

async function modifyPdf() {
      // Fetch an existing PDF document
      // const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/assets/base/with_update_sections.pdf'
      // const url = './assets/base/with_update_sections.pdf'
      const url = 'https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/with_update_sections.pdf'
      const existingPdfBytes = await fetch(url).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())

      console.log(existingPdfBytes)
  
      // // Load a PDFDocument from the existing PDF bytes
      // const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes)

      // // Embed the Helvetica font
      // const helveticaFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica)

      // // Get the first page of the document
      // const pages = pdfDoc.getPages()
      // const firstPage = pages[0]

      // // Get the width and height of the first page
      // const { width, height } = firstPage.getSize()

      // // Draw a string of text diagonally across the first page
      // firstPage.drawText('This text was added with JavaScript!', {
      //   x: 5,
      //   y: height / 2 + 300,
      //   size: 50,
      //   font: helveticaFont,
      //   color: rgb(0.95, 0.1, 0.1),
      //   rotate: degrees(-45),
      // })

      // // Serialize the PDFDocument to bytes (a Uint8Array)
      // const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()

            // // Trigger the browser to download the PDF document
      // // download(pdfBytes, "pdf-lib_modification_example.pdf", "application/pdf");
      // download(pdfBytes, "with_update_sections.pdf", "application/pdf");
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to fetch from a local `file://` url?

Comment: I am indeed trying to get a local file.

Comment: This is expected. Use a server.

Comment: very usefull indeed. the reason why I don't want to use a server is because it needs to run on a local machine.

I would have droped the answer but the post got closed.

In pdf-lib you can use Base64. It is not as straight forward but totaly usable in a local envirement. First use a online converter for PDF to Base64. And then import the string into your javascript. If for one or another reason the string you generated is to big use a line splitter to get the job done.

Comment: You can also run a server on a local machine. Or you can use a file upload if you want to access local files dynamically.

Comment: Yes you could and no I cannot. I should have been more specific as people always make assumptions. I want it to be localy driven without the need to install anything. Also UAX design tells that the less steps a consumer needs to take the better the design. So I don't want the user to actualy need to browse to the file. And it will all be driven off a USB storage device.